# How to implement a translator for one language to another in Android

Tags: android, google-translate

I am implementing a Google Translator simulator to my app. How can I implement this? Some similar source url or related Google api?

Screenshot of this app

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/73620ad386.png

input:

```
from any language <-----translate----------->to any language
```

output:

```
translation of text and  voice of translate text

this app same as google translator
```

Code:

```
checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
startActivityForResult(checkIntent,1);  
 private TextToSpeech mTts;
    protected void onActivityResult(
            int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                // success, create the TTS instance
                mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, null);
            } else {
                // missing data, install it
                Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                installIntent.setAction(
                    TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installIntent);
            }
        }
        mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [Google Language API](http://code.google.com/apis/language/).

> Need to translate your website or application into one or more different languages? With Google Translate, you can dynamically translate text between thousands of language pairs.

Comment: its ok i am using google api translate text will done but voice of translate not working  this is the situation i will try in 2days but no solution  i am forawrd above some source code please forward some valuable solution  advance thanks